# scan doesn't work with rtl8723 driver for realtek module

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, android-wifi

After cloning and compiling rtl8723be driver, I get rtl8723.ko. But upon installing it, along with its dependency cfg80211, wpa_cli doesn't scan the device.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the solution which I did face and solved.

```
modprobe cfg80211
insmod 8723be.ko
```

Create udev rule to create network interface driver expects, wlan0

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
 "SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="sit*", NAME="wlan0""
```

Now reload the rule and start wpa_supplicant daemo

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
iwconfig
//should show wlan0 inerface
# wpa_supplicant -Dwext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -d -B -i wlan0
```

Let's scan now for available APs around

```
wpa_cli
>scan
>scan_result
```

Things will start working now.
To scan and add AP, refer https://gist.github.com/buhman/7162560, explaining very nicely.